# Can't Delete or find a blog post (unknown)

Tags: posts

today I noticed a weird problem in my wordpress woocommerce site. The site has blog enabled. When visiting the site, I can find a blog post, can see as a visitor. But when I logged in as Admin it shows 404 error page.

Also in admin panel I can't find the post. Actually i have only one blog post, but in admin panel it's showing that I published 2 posts.

Please help to fix this
[image: Can't find the post in admin panel]
[image: Only a single post showing while i logged in as admin]
[image: as a visitor seeing an unknown post]
[image: full post here]

Unknown post link https://flixacct.club/club-de-gym-plan-cul-a-tours/

Comment: I'd guess you have a plugin messing with your site here. Cornerstone?

Comment: Try this... ...go to your admin, find that Netflix post and go to edit it... ...then, in the URL address bar in your browser where it says `post.php?post=xxxx&action=edit` change the ID number to `post=2546` so it'd be `post.php?post=2546&action=edit` and see what comes up...

Comment: @TonyDjukic Thanks man. it worked out. I moved that post to the trash by using the way you said. However, tried to permananetly delete the post through admin panel, can't find it. But trash showing as **trash(1)**

Comment: Can you got Trash and click Empty Trash?

Comment: @TonyDjukic it worked man. Many thanks. 100% solved

Comment: Want me to post it as an answer, or you can? That way it gets listed as answered for people that come across it with the same problem.

Comment: @TonyDjukic yes, pls. Post it as an answer. I am new here. Don't know much

Comment: Posted it - please go ahead ad 'Accept' it by clicking not the checkmark under the vote arrows towards the top left of your question.  And let me know if I missed anything so I can update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't really know why this post is there but inaccessible by you, but for anyone having this issue here's how you can attempt to remove it.

You would go to any other post in your dashboard/admin, to edit it.

In your browser URL bar you'd look for this aspect of the URL:

`post.php?post=xxxx&action=edit`

Then, in a different browser tab, on the front end where you can see the problematic post, you want to go to the source code of that page using developer tools and in the `<body>` tag look in the `class=""` attribute for the following class:

`postid-xxxx`  (The xxxx will be the post ID number.)

You want to take that number, go back to the post you can access and in the URL bar replace the number in `post.php?post=xxxx&action=edit` with the id number from the post you can't access. (In this instance it was 2546, so `post.php?post=2546&action=edit`.)

Once you have this elusive post on your edit screen, you can delete it in the Publishing panel at the top right.

What this does though is move it to the 'Trash'.  So now on the main post list screen you'll see 'Trash(1)' but if you click on 'Trash' you still may not see the post.

In the 'Trash' view though, you can click 'Empty Trash' and that will remove the mystery post permanently.

Now, we still don't know what caused that post or why your admin account can't access it, so keep an eye out for more of these, but at least it's cleared out now.